# Annotate plot with ordered pair of cartesian coordinates via Python and MatPlotLib library

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, cartesian-coordinates, multiple-axes

Looking for a solution to properly annotate a subplot with an ordered pair of cartesian coordinates.

My figure is a bar graph of total product quantities with a line graph of the average price for the given products. For additional reference, please see the figure at the end of this article:  https://medium.com/swlh/product-sales-analysis-using-python-863b29026957

Please note, I have two vertical axes where:

- y1 = total quantity of a given product
- y2 = average price of a given product
- y1 & y2 share an x-axis of product categories

Rather than plotting labels "(x, y)", my goal is to plot labels for (y1, y2), i.e. "(qty, price)".

The current error that I am running into is that the list elements in my variable, label, are not recognized as "subscriptable objects".
I am under the impression that the solution is to convert each element of my list into a string, but I am not positive.

df =

| Products | Quantity | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Product1 | 10 | 100.00 |
| Product2 | 15 | 200.00 |
| Product3 | 20 | 150.00 |
| Product2 | 30 | 200.00 |
| Product3 | 50 | 150.00 |

**Attempt**

```
quantity = df.groupby("Products")["Quantity"].sum()
price = df.groupby("Products")["Price"].mean()

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

ax1.bar(Products, quantity, color='.8', alpha =.8)
ax2.plot(Products, price, 'bo-')

ax1.set_xlabel('', fontweight='bold')
ax1.set_ylabel('Quantity', color = 'k', fontweight='bold')
ax2.set_ylabel('Price $', color = 'b', fontweight='bold')
ax1.set_xticklabels(Products, rotation=45, size = 8)

y1 = [i for i in quantity]
y2 = [j for j in price]

label = []
for x, y in zip(y1,y2):
    label.append(f"({x:.2f},{y:.2f})")

for i, label in enumerate(labels):
    plt.annotate(label, xy=(x[i], y[i]), xytext=(5, 5),
    textcoords='offset points', ha='left', va='bottom')
plt.show()
```

**Trouble Area**

```
#can't find a method to convert my list elements from float to string values *inline* with label.append()
label = []
for x, y in zip(y1,y2):
    label.append(f"({x:.2f},{y:.2f})")
```

I feel like I am looking for a solution similar to either:

1. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-annotate-several-points-with-one-text-in-matplotlib
2. https://queirozf.com/entries/add-labels-and-text-to-matplotlib-plots-annotation-examples

Comment: Thank you for the reply @JohanC. My question is confusing because this is still relatively new to me. 
Price and quantity are both lists of float values where price is the mean price for a given quantity of product and quantity is the total sum of a given product type. 
I do not wish to annotate with xy(product[i], quantity[i]) because product is a string. 
To reiterate, I am displaying two different plots on one figure with a shared x-axis where the x-axis are my products. My two y-axes are price and quantity. 
I want to display (y1, y2), i.e (qty of product, $0.00)

Comment: In addition, I agree with your comment about the label variable. This is likely a typo, I think I had meant:
    for i, label in enumerate(labels):

Comment: Thank you again for your reply, @JohanC. 
Am I not defining x, y within my for loop?
`for x, y in zip(y1,y2):`
When I `print(list(zip(y1,y2)))`, I do get a correct list of the ordered pairs with which I wish to annotate my graph

Comment: just added @JohanC, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few misunderstandings in the code:

- When working with `ax1` and `ax2`, it is recommended to use matplotlib's [object-oriented interface](https://matplotlib.org/matplotblog/posts/pyplot-vs-object-oriented-interface/) everywhere. `plt.annotate(...)` will plot on the "current ax", while `ax1.annotate(...)` will plot on `ax1`.
- In the newest matplotlib versions, to plot on `ax1`, the x-coordinate can be given as a string (the name of the product), and the y-coordinate as the numeric quantity.
- Creating the label to plot at the same time as calling the annotation can make the code easier to read.
- To create a loop, in Python it is highly recommended to try to avoid `enumerate(...)` and indexing. Loops are clearer using zip to directly get the list elements.
- To rotate ticks, `ax.tick_params(...)` will leave the existing labels untouched.
- `ax1.margins(y=...)` can make more free space for the labels.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Products': ['Product1', 'Product2', 'Product3', 'Product2', 'Product3'],
                   'Quantity': [10, 15, 20, 30, 50],
                   'Price': [100, 200, 150, 200, 150]})
quantity = df.groupby("Products")["Quantity"].sum()
price = df.groupby("Products")["Price"].mean()
Products = quantity.index

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

ax1.bar(Products, quantity, color='.8', alpha=.8)
ax2.plot(Products, price, 'bo-')

ax1.set_xlabel('', fontweight='bold')
ax1.set_ylabel('Quantity', color='k', fontweight='bold')
ax2.set_ylabel('Price $', color='b', fontweight='bold')
ax1.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=45, labelsize=8)

for prod, quant, prc in zip(Products, quantity, price):
    ax1.annotate(f'{quant:.2f}, {prc:.2f}', xy=(prod, quant), xytext=(0, 5),
                 textcoords='offset points', ha='center', va='bottom')
ax1.margins(y=0.2)  # more space on top of the bars
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: annotating using strings as coordinate]

Comment: Thank you very much, @JohanC! I see I should have zipped all x3 axes within my for loop v. only two and and now have a better understanding of `plt.annotate` v. `axis.annotate`. I also appreciate your additional suggestions. This conversation was helpful!

Comment: would you have any additional suggestions on how to set the labels just above the actual, plotted points of the line graph? I.e. I'm trying to set the ordered pair label (45, 200) at some offset distance just above the cartesian point, y2 = 200

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. I updated `xy=()` from `xy=(prod, quant)`  to  `xy=(prod, prc)`